# Cannot get port forwarding to work with Advanced Tomato

Tags: tomato

I'm trying to forward port 80 on my wan to one of my local computers for testing a web service. But I cannot get it to work and I don't really know where to start.

I did set up TCP port 80 to my computers LAN address.

One strange thing is that when I look at the UI in AdvancedTomato I see one external IP (starting with 100) but when I look at wanip.info I get another IP (starting with 37)

Really strange. Any ideas?

Comment: Your ISP is likely using [Carrier Grade NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT). Please read [Alternatives to Port Forwarding & NAT](https://portforward.com/help/alt-to-pf.htm): "There are four major problems that you may run into that would require alternatives to port forwarding. " ...

Comment: Thank you so much! Could get my ISP to give me a real public IP address. I didn't know about this (it was 10+ years since I did this the last time).

Comment: Ask your ISP if this is possible. It may not be as CGN is being used to get around a shortage of IPv4 addresses.